# Text Change with parameter in Python

Tags: python, pandasql, pandas-datareader

if i want to change the query with parameter.

i don't want to Run Sql with this Query .
I want to write the query in txt file and Share the query with another people.

But Pandas.text_sql,  Pandas.read_sql_query this function will be run using query.

So i want to find the Text change with parameter similar with pandas.read_sql_query

which function can i change the "read_sql_query" ?
 i really a little know the python ..
 if you know the things,  help me ~

```
text_sql = pandas.read_sql_query(""" select * from %s""", %(table_name),conn)

f= open(file_name+'.txt','w+')
f.write(text_sql)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I completely misunderstood the question when I gave my first answer.

You want to write a query into a file and send that file off to other people, so in your question `pandas` has nothing to do with the sql query.  In the examples you gave pandas is acting as an interface to wrap-up the sql queries. These functions would do some processing on the data and return the result of the request in some structured format.

How ever here we just want the requests themselves. So you can work with the strings by themselves.

```
sql_request_string = "select * from " + table_name
with open(file_name, 'w+') as f:
    f.write(sql_request_string)
```

Now that snippet is not particularly use full on its own. However we can wrap it up in a function then use it man times.

```
def save_request_string(table_name,filename,field="*"):
"""write a sql request string to file"""
request_template = "select {field} from {table}"
with open(file_name, 'w+') as f:
    f.write(request_template.format(field=field, table=table_name))
```

You can use that function to write many requests to a file by looping over a list of table names that you have assembled for example. Then email the file off to your friend.

Now if you want to email the file from your python script as well. I am afraid I can't help you there.

Comment: umm...it also running sql in db??..  i don't want to running to sql ㅠㅠ

Comment: i want to change the query with parameter and store this query in file

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what you mean. Are you asking how to write a sql query into a file so you can send it to someone else? Or so you can send several to someone else?

Comment: yeah 
i want to know how to write a sql query into a file 
and send it someone !

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to send the text in a text file just do this, with `table_name` being a string

```
f= open(file_name+'.txt','w+')
f.write('select * from '+table_name)
f.close()
```

Comment: i want to fine a function ;;